# How to have logs from a Lutris launched game?

Tags: wine, debug

I am trying to play fortnite with wine, but I have disconnection issues so I would like to have a closer look at what is happening.

I have already tried to launch the launcher exe from the terminal with the command

```
~/Games/fortnite/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Epic Games/Launcher/Portal/Binaries/Win32$ wine EpicGamesLauncher.exe
```

but the game does not even start.

Thank you for your help

EDIT: The simplest is to find the log file from the game, in the simulated windows folders. Here I used (with-out solving my connection issue) the built-in debug tool from the launcher.